# How can I write a 5add9 chord in lilypond?

Tags: notation, chords, lilypond

When I write `g:5.9` or `g:9^7.3` in a Notes block, the chord is correct.
But when I write it in a ChordNames block, it produces `G9` rather than `G5add9`.

Is this a missing feature, is there a workaround, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: 5add9 is just a sus2 chord.

Comment: It has a different sound, because you stack two fifths and do not directly hear the second. But when including inversions it is equivalent, yes.

Answer (score 3):

I at least found a workaround in the documentation: Adding a pitchPrefix

```
\set additionalPitchPrefix = "5add"
g:5.9
```

Answer (score 2):

It's an unusual chord, so it isn't included in the list of chords that are recognised by LilyPond.

Fortunately, there is a way to teach LilyPond chord names/symbols, it just requires a little bit of Scheme.

Adapting the example on this page [2.7.2 Displaying Chords - Customizing chord names](https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.23/Documentation/notation/displaying-chords#customizing-chord-names) (under *Chord name exceptions*):

```
chExceptionMusic = {
  <c g d'>1-\markup { \super "5add9" }
  <c e f g>1-\markup { \super "add4" }
}

chExceptions = #(append
  (sequential-music-to-chord-exceptions chExceptionMusic #t)
  ignatzekExceptions)
  
\new ChordNames {   
    \set chordNameExceptions = #chExceptions
%   \set additionalPitchPrefix = "add"
    
    \chordmode {
        c1:5.9
        g1:5.9
        g1:9^7.3
        g1:3.4.5
        g1:5.6.9
    }
}
```

Using the `additionalPitchPrefix` method (as in your answer) is going to affect *all* chords that LilyPond thinks are "add" chords. But using `chExceptions` is *only* going to affect chords that are of the type 1-5-9.

Chord name exceptions also has the advantage of making it possible to have more custom chords.